# Why gedit is not opening a file from terminal?

Tags: command-line, gedit, vps

I've a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS with no graphical environment installed. In that VPS, I'm trying to open a file from terminal using gedit with this command

```
gedit config/database.yml
```

But unfortunately it is showing following error

```
(process:3790): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Cannot open display: 
Run 'gedit --help' to see a full list of available command line options.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what is config is that a directory?

Comment: If there is no graphical environment installed, then how would you like to start a graphical program? If on the other hand you are connecting to the server with ssh, then you can use X11 forwarding, and that way you can use gedit.

Answer (score 2):

`gedit` is a graphical editor. All graphical applications need an environment variable called `$DISPLAY`.

If you have running graphical session start `gedit` like this:

```
user@host:~# DISPLAY=:0 gedit config/database.yml
```

In case you dont have access to a graphical session try

`user@host:~# nano config/database.yml`